# How to format text correctly using printf() (Java)

Tags: java, printf

Hello I want to print something so they are aligned.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        //creatureT += "[" + temp.get(i).getCreatureType() + "]";
        creatureS = "\t" + temp.get(i).getName();
        creatureT = " [" + temp.get(i).getCreatureType() + "]";
        System.out.printf(creatureS + "%15a",creatureT + "\n");
   }
```

and the output is

```
    Lily      [Animal]
    Mary         [NPC]
    Peter      [Animal]
    Squash          [PC]
```

I just want the [Animal], [NPC], and [PC] to be aligned like

```
    Lily      [Animal]
    Mary      [NPC]
    Peter     [Animal]
    Squash    [PC]
```

Say I know that no name will be greater then 15 characters.

Comment: surely some of your past responses helped you. Why not accept some of them? It would show that you appreciate the time and effort put into trying to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll find it's a lot easier to do all of the formatting in the format string itself, i.e.

```
System.out.printf("\t%s [%s]\n", creature.getName(), creature.getCreatureType());
```

which would print

```
  Lily [Animal]
  etc...
```

You can consult the [String formatting documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) on the exact format to use to print a minimum of 15 spaces for a string to achieve the alignment effect, something like

```
System.out.printf("\t%15s[%s]\n", creature.getName(), creature.getCreatureType());
```

The key is specifying a "width" of 15 chars for the first item in the argument list in `%15s`.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that you describe the **full** format in the format string (the first argument) and provide all **dynamic** data as additional properties.

You mix those two by building the format string from dynamic data (the creature name, it seems), which will lead to unexpected results. Do this instead:

```
Creature t = temp.get(i);
System.out.printf("\t%15s [%s]\n", t.getname(), t.getCreatureType());
```

Answer (score 0):

formating like this %15s makes something like text aline right.
You have to write %-15s to make place for first string in 15 charts. 
1st string will be align left and next string will start from 16th chart

```
Lily           [Animal]
Mary           [NPC]
Peter          [Animal]
Squash         [PC]
```