# System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n", s1, x) How to interpret it

Tags: java

In each line of output there should be two columns:
The first column contains the String and is left justified using exactly 15 characters.
The second column contains the integer, expressed in exactly 3 digits; if the original input has less than three digits, you must pad your output's leading digits with zeroes.

can someone explain the  `System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n", s1, x);`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("================================");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            String s1=sc.next();
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n", s1, x);
        }
        System.out.println("================================");

}

}
```

Comment: That's a `printf`, just like `String.format` or `System.out.format`. Check the [`format String Syntax`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: `System.out.printf` seems to work like C's `printf` function. More info here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @axelH i know what's println I am interested in knowing what the content inside it means?

Comment: just edit it my previous comment. And by the way, that's NOT a println! That question is asking to define a syntax that is well documented. So for me, this is off-topic because it can't be clearly explained here and mostly because this is asking for guide

Comment: @NathanShiraini What's the meaning of command inside the System.out.printf

Comment: Did you search for the answer before posting the question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format text correctly using printf() (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806886/how-to-format-text-correctly-using-printf-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically every `%...` is gonna be replaced by one of the arguments of `printf`. What is after the `%` sign is a format specifier.

In `%-15s`:

- `-` means: left-justified
- `15` means: if the result is less than 15 characters long, add spaces until it is 15 characters long
- `s` means: convert the parameter into a string with `toString` and use the result

In `%03d`:

- `0` means: pad with `0`s instead of spaces
- `3` means: make it at least 3 characters long
- `d` means: the argument will be an integer number, format it as a base-10 number.

`%n` is the same as `\n` on *NIX or `\r\n` on Windows.

You will get more info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

**EDIT** based on remarks by [AxelH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4391450/axelh) and [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner)

Comment: `s` or `S` means much more : "_If the argument arg is null, then the result is "null". If arg implements Formattable, then arg.formatTo is invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking arg.toString()._". So you could pass a lot of think as an argument ;)

Comment: "use it verbatim" not quite: it means insert the string which is the result of calling [`Objects.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object)) on the parameter.

Comment: And the correct syntax for Java is [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). Because the `printf` of c++ is not necessarly going to stay the same

Comment: "outputs nothing" no, it outputs the system dependent newline character sequence.

Comment: @AndyTurner my bad, I based myself on the C version of printf... Gonna edit now.

Comment: A last note, `\n` is system dependent, `%n` is better because it will use the _platform-specific line separator_. So there a different. EDIT : Well, you catch that too. Nice and complet answer

Answer (score 2):

Its Java [formatter syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

first half - %-15s

- % - says that what follows is an argument that will be formatted.
- s - says youre formatting a string
- 15 - number of characters you put into string
- and finally - means string is gonna be justified to the left

second half - %03d

- d means youll be adding integers
- 0 means youll be adding 0's where necessary
- 3 means you need to add 3 digits
- %n is [System.line_separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) - basically outputs new line. It does the same as /n but %n is portable across platforms (credit @AxelH)

Comment: @AxelH minor interruption @ my side, completed :)

Comment: I meant `%n` actually ;) the `System.line_separator` flag. A good answer should be complete ;)