# I want to understand what symbols like % mean in Java and if there is a link with all the symbols. Thanks

Tags: java, syntax

I am doing an exercise for methods in java from my workbook in my own free time, I saw that someone had solved this problem using:

```
System.out.printf("%-12.1f", celsius);
```

what does the `%` symbol mean as well as everything else in the parentheses. Sorry if this is a noob question as I am new to the website and am just now trying to learn the language again after not touching it for a year. Thanks! Code attached down below for full context.

```
public class Main {


    /** Main Method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Display table
        System.out.println( // Display header
                "Celsius     Fahrenheit     |     Fahrenheit     Celsius\n" +
                        "----------------------------------------------------------");
        // Display data
        for (double celsius = 40.0, fahrenheit = 120.0;
             celsius >= 31.0; celsius--, fahrenheit -= 10) {
            System.out.printf("%-12.1f", celsius);
            System.out.printf("%-15.1f|", celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius));
            System.out.printf("     %-15.1f", fahrenheit);
            System.out.printf("%-7.2f\n\n", fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit));
        }
    }

    /** Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit */
    public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) {
        return (9.0 / 5) * celsius + 32;
    }
    /** Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius */
    public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {
        return (5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `printf` function uses a format string to output text, where the `%` sign is used to describe the format. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5806886/14955  This is a standard from C, used in many languages, not just Java.

Comment: `%-12.1f` means that you want to output a `f`loating point number with space for `12` digits before the decimal point `.` and `1` after, also keeping space for the sign `-`.  The number to be formatted is the second argument to `printf(format, value)`.

Comment: Documentation is your friend.  It shows that [System.out](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out) is of type PrintStream.  PrintStream’s [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...%29) method has documentation that links to the [format string syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...%29), which fully explains `%` usage.